# Pandas - Set value in Column based on values in 3 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dump of transactions. Columns in the data set provide information regarding Currency and which FS each transaction flows to.

I want to translate currencies at two different rates depending on which FS the transaction flows to. There are two currencies USD and CAD. There are two FS. I have a column with all amounts in USD and one with all in CAD. See table below for an example.

```
FS  CUR USD     CAD    USD_FS

BS  USD 1000    1364    X
BS  USD 2000    2729    X
IS  CAD 300     409     X
IS  USD 55      75      X
BS  CAD 1312    1790    X
IS  CAD 3156    4306    X
IS  USD 32165   43881   X
BS  CAD 32156   43869   X
```

The psuedo code i want to implement in pandas is:

```
ye_rate = 1.3642
average_rate = 1.2957
if FS == 'BS' and CUR == 'CAD':
   USD_FS = CAD/ye_rate
else if FS == 'IS' and CUR == 'USD':
   USD_FS = CAD/average_rate
else:
   USD_FS = USD
```

This is what I have in pandas so far:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df.loc[i]['Currency'] == 'CAD':
        if df.loc[i]['FS'] == 'BS':
            df.loc[i]['USD_FS'] = df.loc[i]['CAD']/ye_rate
        if df.loc[i]['FS'] == 'IS':
            df.loc[i]['USD_FS'] = df.loc[i]['CAD']/average_rate
```

I get this error:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

For the sample table above, I want the following output:

```
FS  CUR USD     CAD     USD_FS

BS  USD 1000    1364    1000
BS  USD 2000    2729    2000
IS  CAD 300     409     409/average_rate
IS  USD 55      75      55
BS  CAD 1312    1790    1790/ye_rate
IS  CAD 3156    4306    4306/average_rate
IS  USD 32165   43881   32165
BS  CAD 32156   43869   43869/ye_rate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need `np.select`

```
rate1=1
rate2=2
s1=(df.FS=='BS')&(df.CUR=='CAD')
s2=(df.FS=='IS')&(df.CUR=='USD')
np.select([s1,s2],[df.CAD*rate1,df.CAD*rate2],default = df.CAD)
#df.CAD=np.select([s1,s2],[df.CAD*rate1,df.CAD*rate2],default = df.CAD)

Out[280]: 
array([ 1364,  2729,   409,   150,  1790,  4306, 43881, 43869],
      dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I edited my question slightly and was able to get the desired result with this:

`s1 = (df.FS=='BS')&(df.Currency=='CAD')`

`s2 = (df.FS=='IS')&(df.Currency=='CAD')`

`df['USD_FS'] = np.select([s1,s2],[df.CAD/ye_rate, df.CAD/average_rate],default = df.USD)`

Answer (score 0):

If the desire is to continue relying on Pandas only (even though it's built on top of Numpy), the proper syntax for using the .loc indexer is:

`df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]`

Per Pandas' [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html):

> This is the correct access method
>
> In [305]: dfc = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'],'B':[1,2,3]})
>
> In [306]: dfc.loc[0,'A'] = 11

...

> This will not work at all, and so should be avoided
>
> dfc.loc[0]['A'] = 1111